# Switch fullscreen monitor in Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

What does it take to create a graphics menu in Unreal where the user may select which monitor to run the game window in?

I have browsed the source code for `GenericApplication`, `UGameUserSettings`, `FDisplayMetrics`, `FSlateApplication`, `FMonitorInfo`, `SWindow` etc., but nowhere did I find it specified how to actually select a monitor. I can pretty easily see which monitors are available using this code:

```cpp
FSlateApplication& slateApp = FSlateApplication::Get();
FDisplayMetrics displayMetrics;
slateApp.GetInitialDisplayMetrics(displayMetrics);

for (const auto& mInfo : displayMetrics.MonitorInfo)
{
    // FMonitorInfo struct for each monitor
}
```

There was this single [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/unrealengine/comments/3j7bo4/is_it_possible_to_choose_the_default_screen_in_a/), which was the only place I could find where a solution is suggested - and it kind of works, except what to do if there are 3 monitors side by side?

Is there no way of specifying a monitor somewhere? Or can we create a new window on a specific monitor and specify that window as the "primary" window?

Or is this something that simply cannot be done reliable with Unreal?

Answer (score 0):

Just had to use the correct phrasing during online search. Also, credits where due in [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXgjg5SEGTk) by CodeLikeMe.

I'm not really sure I want to just copy/paste their code here since I didn't really write it. I can, if people really want it / it is good practice.